# Why are redundant records being inserted with this TSQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, temp-tables

When I run this portion of my Stored Procedure in LINQPad:

```
create table #temp1
(
    MemberNo varchar(25),
    MemberItemCode varchar(25),
    ShortName varchar(25),
    ItemCode varchar(50),
    WVItem varchar(25),
    WVItemCode varchar(25),
    WVDescription varchar(250),
    Week1Usage varchar(25),
    Week1Price varchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO #temp1 (MemberNo, MemberItemCode, WVItemCode, WVDescription, Week1Usage, Week1Price) 
select MemberNo, ItemCode, WVItemCode, Description, SUM(QtyShipped), Price
FROM InvoiceDetail 
WHERE Unit=@Unit
AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @Begin AND @EndDate
GROUP BY Description, MemberNo, ItemCode, WVItemCode, Price

select * from #temp1 order by memberitemcode;
```

...I get what I hope for, namely one row of data for each MemberItemCode, with the QtyShipped summed in its column.

However, when I populate a related table with the "Week2" values, and then combine them, like this:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[priceVarianceTest]
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime 
AS 

DECLARE @Week1End datetime = DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate);
DECLARE @Week2Begin datetime = DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate);

. . .

create table #temp2
(
    MemberNo varchar(25),
    Week2Usage varchar(25),
    Week2Price varchar(25)
)

-- populate week2 vals
INSERT INTO #temp2 (MemberNo, Week2Usage, Week2Price)
select MemberNo, Sum(QtyShipped), Price
FROM InvoiceDetail 
WHERE Unit=@Unit
AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate
GROUP BY Description, MemberNo, Price;

-- now I have some records with week1 vals, and some with week2 vals; combine them into a third table
create table #tempCombined
(
    MemberNo varchar(25),
    MemberItemCode varchar(25),
    ShortName varchar(25),
    ItemCode varchar(50),
    WVItem varchar(25),
    WVItemCode varchar(25),
    WVDescription varchar(250),
    Week1Usage varchar(25),
    Week2Usage varchar(25),
    UsageVariance varchar(25),
    Week1Price varchar(25),
    Week2Price varchar(25),
    PriceVariance varchar(25),
    PercentageOfPriceVariance varchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO #tempCombined (MemberNo, MemberItemCode, WVDescription, Week1Usage, Week1Price, week2Usage, week2Price)
select t1.MemberNo, t1.MemberItemCode, t1.WVDescription, t1.Week1Usage, t1.Week1Price, t2.Week2Usage, t2.Week2Price
FROM #temp1 as t1
JOIN #temp2 as t2 on t1.MemberNo = t2.MemberNo
```

...the result set I get has gone so far south that I can see Kudzu growing all over it: I get 40 milliion records for each MemberItemCode, instead of the summation and grouping working as it should.

Why would this be the case when I'm summing/grouping the second temp table, too, and then simply combining the two tables into a third one and returning that?

### UPDATE

If I convert the JOIN into a LEFT JOIN, it solves the problem I'm bemoaning, but the Week2 values (Week2Usage and Week2Price) go silent/dark.

### UPDATE 2

I was hoping Justin Cave's comment was the key to the issue, but I changed my code to this:

```
-- populate week2 vals
INSERT INTO #temp2 (MemberNo, ItemCode, WVDescription, Week2Usage, Week2Price)
select MemberNo, ItemCode, Description, SUM(QtyShipped), Price
FROM InvoiceDetail 
WHERE Unit=@Unit
AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate
GROUP BY MemberNo, ItemCode, Description, Price;

-- now I have some records with week1 vals, and some with week2 vals; combine them into a third table
create table #tempCombined
(
    MemberNo varchar(25),
    MemberItemCode varchar(25),
    ShortName varchar(25),
    ItemCode varchar(50),
    WVItem varchar(25),
    WVItemCode varchar(25),
    WVDescription varchar(250),
    Week1Usage varchar(25),
    Week2Usage varchar(25),
    UsageVariance varchar(25),
    Week1Price varchar(25),
    Week2Price varchar(25),
    PriceVariance varchar(25),
    PercentageOfPriceVariance varchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO #tempCombined (MemberNo, MemberItemCode, WVDescription, Week1Usage, Week1Price, week2Usage, week2Price)
select t1.MemberNo, t1.MemberItemCode, t1.WVDescription, t1.Week1Usage, t1.Week1Price, t2.Week2Usage, t2.Week2Price
FROM #temp1 as t1
LEFT JOIN #temp2 as t2 on t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode AND t1.MemberNo = t2.MemberNo and t1.WVDescription = t2.WVDescription
```

...but it makes no difference - the "Week2" vals are still NULL.

### UPDATE 3

By changing the join type to FULL OUTER JOIN, I now get hundreds of records with Week 1 vals and no Week 2 vals, and hundreds of records with Week 2 vals and no Week 1 vals, but none have values for both weeks.

The count of #tempCombined is the count of #temp1 and #temp2 combined (IOW, they are piled together, instead of merged).

### UPDATE 4

I won't be able to test it until Monday, but I'm thinking maybe this will work:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP1 (MEMBERITEMCODE, WEEK1USAGE, WEEK1PRICE)
SELECT MEMBERITEMCODE, SUM(QTYSHIPPED), PRICE FROM INVOICEDETAIL 
WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @BEGDATE AND @WEEK1END
GROUP BY MEMBERITEMCODE, PRICE

INSERT INTO TEMP2 (MEMBERITEMCODE, WEEK2USAGE, WEEK2PRICE)
SELECT MEMBERITEMCODE, SUM(QTYSHIPPED), PRICE FROM INVOICEDETAIL 
WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @WEEK2BEGIN AND @ENDDATE
GROUP BY MEMBERITEMCODE, PRICE

INSERT INTO TEMP3 (MEMBERITEMCODE, WEEK1USAGE, WEEK1PRICE, WEEK2USAGE, WEEK2PRICE)
SELECT T1.MEMBERITEMCODE, T1.WEEK1USAGE, T1.WEEK1PRICE, T2.WEEK2USAGE, T2.WEEK2PRICE
FROM TEMP1 T1
LEFT JOIN TEMP2 T2 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T2.MEMBERITEMCODE
```

Comment: Does `memberno` in temp1 and temp2 uniquely identify each row? To see where I'm going  consider the difference in the results from the two queries in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0110/2)

Comment: `#temp1` has one row per member per item (assuming that `ItemCode`, `WVItemCode`, `Description`, and `Price` are all the same for a single item).  `#temp2` has one row per member per item (assuming that `Description` and `Price`) are all the same for a single item.  But you're joining them only on `MemberNo`.  Shouldn't you join on `MemberNo` and `Description` (or, more likely, include `ItemCode` in `#temp2` and join on `MemberNo` and `ItemCode`)?

Comment: Please see Update 2.

Comment: As a test I suggest you select from #tempCombined and add a `WHERE week2Usage IS NOT NULL` to identify if any rows are not null. It's possible that these week2 NULL's are all valid - there is no match between the two tables - and in fact some non-nulls do exist. I don't know what the objective of your SP is. Do you want to find activity that only occurs in both weeks? Activity in either week?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: The objective is to compare activity between two weeks - did the price change? Did the usage change? If so, how much? Some vals yet to be added are PriceVariance, UsageVariance, and PriceVariancePercentage.

Comment: So you want to include data for these cases: no activity in week 1 and activity in week 2. Activity in week 1 and no activity in week 2. Activity in both weeks? For this you need a FULL OUTER JOIN. But before we go there you need to satisfy yourself that the current data is correct. Forst confirm that not _all_ resulting records are null. Then confirm that the NULLs are correct in that they indicate records with activity in week 1 and no activity in week 2. Take a couple of records and test them manually.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Okay, I did the "WHERE week2Usage IS NOT NULL" and it *does* return records, but the Week2 Vals are still null. Seems bizarre/macbare to me (that there are records but that those columns are null), but I will try the FULL OUTER JOIN you mentioned.

Comment: "it does return records, but the Week2 Vals are still null" Why would you expect there to be no null week2 values? In this case a null week2 value indicates there was activity in week1 and no activity in week2. So like I said in my last postgo back and confirm that this is correct. Take a couple of example records and check individually that this is the case. You need it understand what that means. If you don't then the FULL OUTER JOIN is going to confuse you even more. Go back, take a few sample records and understand what is going on before you make your query more complicated.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I already know there are (many) records that contain values in both weeks, they are just not displaying; but when I "select * from #tempCombined WHERE (Week1Usage IS NOT NULL) AND (Week2Usage IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY PADescription, Week1Usage DESC;" it returns 0 records.

Comment: You need to pick some test records and work your way back - check #temp1 and #temp2 and see if they exist. If your test records are missing then the issue is in the select statement populating the temp table. I can't see your records or database so I can only suggest troubleshooting methods like this. looking at your code, I assume your are populating `@Unit` with something valid?

Comment: Basically your 'redundant records' issue is solved now that you have the correct join. You might want to do some more detailed checking and open a new question.